# h:dataTable nested in ui:repeat, updating of inputText values not working

Tags: jsf-2

I render an ArrayList (menu.specifications) containing custom objects (POJOs) in several h:dataTables on the same page. Each h:dataTable contains a different range of the elements of the ArrayList. One column contains an h:inputText tag.

After user input and submit, only the inputText tags of the last dataTable are updated. The others
remain unchanged.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{menu.groupTitles}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
        <h:dataTable rendered="#{menu.points[loop.index].y>0}" value="#{menu.specifications}" 
            first="#{menu.points[loop.index].x}" rows="#{menu.points[loop.index].y}" var="rowVar" border="1">                  
            <h:inputText  value="#{rowVar.pvalue}"  id="pvalue"/>
```

I tried this as well:

```
<h:inputText value="#{menu.specifications[rowVar.index].pvalue}" id="pvalue"/>
```

Explanation of references:

- `menu.points[loop.index].x` = first element of the ArrayList to show in the dataTable
- `menu.points[loop.index].y` = number of elements to show in the dataTable
- `menu.groupTitles` = titles of the different dataTables

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue by the dataTables all having the same ID when generated by a `ui:repeat` tag. See also this [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830) at the Mojarra JIRA. However, I don't have a solution yet. It seems to exist since the JSF 1.2 days, because the problem first occured when switching from JBoss 4.2.2 to 4.3.3 which included a JSF 1.2 version upgrade as well.